# Compressing 3 number data in a byte

Tags: c++, c, encoding, compression, encode

So, I am using C and I have 6 kind of command numbers as 0-5, want to take 3 of them in combination, and save the combination in single byte. So the problem is how can I encode these numbers?  For example if I use binary encoding so 5 is 101, then I can’t save 555 as 101101101 has 9 bits and a byte has only 8.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You cannot do that.  The number of possible combos, (343), exceeds 256.

Comment: You always need at least three bits to represent 6 symbols, so you can't represent three distinct symbols in a single byte.

Comment: Sorry 0-5 ,6kind of symbol

Comment: @MartinJames sorry ,symbols are 0-5 so there is 216 combos

Comment: @MartinJames Why do you think that there is no alternative,  if you say that you can not do it?

Comment: @Michi: OP made a mistake with 7 kinds of command instead of just 6. and total number of combination go from `7 * 7 * 7` is `343`  (greater than `255`) to `6 * 6 * 6` (`216`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I noticed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Treat the three numbers as a three-digit base-6 number, and calculate its value:

```
value = num1 * 36 + num2 * 6 + num3

num1 = value / 36
num2 = (value / 6) % 6
num3 = value % 6
```

The value will be in the range 0 to 215, so it fits in a byte.

Comment: A tangential comment. If you need to do this a lot (perhaps for a colour table) and you find that / and % are slow: you could use a LUT for decoding; or with some care you can maybe approximate division using multiply-and-shift (it only needs to be accurate enough to work for those 216 values).